# "Public" attributes of an object with their values

Tags: python

A search only showed long code and/or `dir()`.

Is there really no simple one liner to get all the functions attributes (preferably, those that do not start with `__`) together with their values? I operate on Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
[(name, getattr(obj, name)) for name in dir(obj) if not name.startswith('__')]
```

Edit: To omit methods, add this to the condition:

```
and type(getattr(obj, name)) != types.MethodType
```

Comment: Almost perfect - can we make this not return methods?

Comment: Is this 2.7 valid? `NameError: name 'types' is not defined`

Comment: @FooBar: `import types`

Comment: Note that `name.startswith('__')` won't actually catch private attributes, because those get name-mangled to not start with `__`. It'll only catch things like `__init__` and `__repr__`.